# BigQuery storage write API Datetime

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I'm trying to send datetime to bigquery with storage write API.

My BQ model has a datetime column.
I parse my java model with Jackson to json, resolving to this (try both ways with escaped literal):

```
{"last_updated":"2021-09-20T10:15:26.796731"}

{"last_updated":"'2021-09-20T10:15:26.796731'"}
```

And bigquery returns this error.

```
JSONObject does not have a int64 field at root.last_updated.
```

As I read in the documentation, it should support string literals as datetime: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#datetime_literals

Comment: hmm are you sure you are passing ' ' string literal? :)

Comment: updated my question. I tried adding single quotes to the date already, same response

Comment: I have replicated your scenario and I have the same issue when writing DATETIME values using the BigQuery Storage Write API. The same has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/201397012). However, we cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates on the progress and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: Hi @Nacho, the latest version of java-bigquerystorage (v2.3.3) now supports `int64` encoding of  DATETIME input values. Use the dependency as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar Github issue: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage/issues/1330

It's been fixed in [v2.3.3](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage/releases/tag/v2.3.3) onwards. So updating the Java client library version should resolve this issue.